# Error en instalación de base de datos (SQL) en modulo para Prestashop

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqldb, prestashop1.7

en estos momentos estoy tratando de creare una base de datos SQL para mi pagina de comercio que estoy trabajando con prestashop, pero llego rato que rato que no encuentro solución a este error que me aparece a reiniciar el modulo en el gestor:

---

{error}

Excepción emitida por el módulo urimoduletest en reset.
Error al reiniciar el módulo urimoduletest.

You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"id") ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 4

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ps_urimoduletest_text ( id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, texto VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id") ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

---

{capture del error}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

llevo rato mirando y mirando pero no le encuentro solución, cual seria el problema?

(Version de prestashop: 1.7.8.1)

Codigo:

// DB INSTALLDB
public function installDB(){
Db::getInstance()->execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '.*DB_PREFIX*.$this->name.'_text (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
texto VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY("id")
) ENGINE=' . *MYSQL_ENGINE* . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8');
return true;
}

Comment: Ya haz intentado modifiar la consulta `PRIMARY KEY ("id")` por `PRIMARY KEY (id)` parece que ese es todo el problema. aunque al tener un codificado UTF8 deberia de aceptar las comillas

Comment: @Nor
Si, ya lo pude corregir, era un simple error en la consulta pero ya esta solucionada y funcional correctamente :D